Why were there so many OSes that had the name "DOS" in them?
Why were there so many OSes named "DOS" in them? For example, there was PC-DOS, DR-DOS, MS-DOS, and probably a few others. Couldn't the names of those OSes have something apart from having DOS in its name (maybe something much more creative)?

All the ones you list (and FreeDOS, RxDOS, ROM-DOS, PTS-DOS) belong to the 86-DOS compatibles, so including the "DOS" name part signals that they share some of their interfaces and structures (more or less). It may be more interesting to investigate other uses of the term DOS that weren't for 8086-based machines.

Ask yourself, would you have wasted time and money on names when people were interested getting a DOS at all and ripping the product out of your hands, no matter what it's called? Name games are only needed in a saturated market where difference in advertisement replaces features.

For comparison, the BBC Micro family didn't hard-code the storage types in its MOS (Machine Operating System).  It supported cassette and ROM by default, but you could add a DFS (Disk Filing System) or ADFS (Advanced Disk Filing System) ROM; there was also a Network Filing System — and probably many more, as anyone could write one.

Digital Research also sold Concurrent DOS and Multiuser DOS.

The 8-bit trinity from 1977, Tandy TRS-80, Commodore PET, and Apple II, all had disk operating systems with DOS in their names by 1979. Atari had one by 1980. Seems DOS was already in use by DEC before then, not sure if others besides DEC were also using it before then. You could say it was 'standard' terminology by the time the IBM PC came out.

Related (if not outright duplicate): https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2406/15334

why were there so many OSes with an x in their name: AIX, HP-UX, IRIX, Linux, Minix, Ultrix, Xenix...

@ilkkachu Hmm, maybe Musk knows?

PC-compatability was a thing. And pcs ran DOS.

@ilkkachu That one is not exactly random either…

How is this not a Question more of your personal taste than anything useful?
Did you notice, one effort to fight that trend was Jack Tramiel, of Commodore, launching his own Tramiel Operating System under the name 'TOS' had two huge drawbacks?
More obviously, who was going to recognise - or even find - 'TOS' in a world full of 'DOS'?
In British English, who was not going to associate 'TOS' with terms like 'Toss…' or 'Tosser…' or 'Tossing…' all of which, please search in your engine of choice.

Regarding the three in your question specifically, the similar naming is intentional. PC DOS and MS-DOS are largely the same; PC DOS is the IBM version, MS-DOS is the Microsoft version. DR DOS is Digital Research’s clone, and it would probably have been confusing for their target market to name it something else; it was one of a number of Digital Research operating systems designed to compete with MS-DOS while allowing users to run DOS programs, starting with DOS Plus.
“DOS” means “disk operating system”, and that was used as a description for operating systems capable of handling disks (on micros, as opposed to operating systems capable only of handling cassettes, typically), or for extensions to the core operating system, adding support for disks. The key feature was disk support. The name goes back to the sixties, with IBM’s DOS/360. Wikipedia has an article listing many different operating systems with “DOS” in their name.
Bear in mind that back in the day (and arguably still today in most cases) people just used what came with their computer, or in the case of some DOS implementations, with their disk drives, so creative names weren’t particularly important, at least initially. Manufacturers produced operating systems with disk support, and named them DOS because that describes what they do; once that name was established (on various platforms), competitors tended to use similar names to make it obvious that their products served a similar purpose. Later names did tend to be slightly more creative: for example Apple DOS was replaced by ProDOS, and Atari DOS had many alternatives with names like SmartDOS, SuperDOS, Turbo-DOS... And then of course Windows, which is also a descriptive name.

"it was one of a number of Digital Research operating systems designed to compete with MS-DOS," - Going by this metric I think CP/M-86 would count as a competitor to the MS/IBM DOSes already, and that retained the system family name from its predecessors. The DR "DOS" brand specifically came about, I believe, because these systems were 86-DOS compatibles and so they competed more directly as compatible replacements to the MS/IBM offering, not just for running on the same systems but rather not requiring different applications etc.

Fair point, I’ve clarified that I was thinking of competitors with support for DOS programs. What changed with DR DOS is that it was designed from the ground up as a DOS, rather than a CP/M variant with DOS compatibility bolted on.

Some of the PCMODE+FDOS structure from DOS Plus is retained in the (Enhanced) DR-DOS kernel sources, and some of its copyright statements reach as far back as 1976, so there is still a certain resemblance. Also, DR-DOS was variously known as Novell DOS / NWDOS, Caldera OpenDOS, and Caldera DR-DOS, so it takes up more names than even the MS/IBM family of DOS systems =)

Heh, MS-DOS racks up quite a few if you count OEMs — Z-DOS, Epson DOS, Compaq DOS, etc. Ironically the first in that line, QDOS, doesn’t refer to disks ;-).

True! But there was another ZDOS not based on MS-DOS. I recall that it didn't display the Carriage Return after the input line when you called interrupt 21h function 0Ah, hence my note in https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/752ea2faccd8/source/lineio.asm#l2721 This line goes back all the way to 2010's initial commit so I tested running on ZDOS before then: https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/5eef5847c863/source/debug.asm#l5787

Don't forget DOS-11

And for the younger readers - there were other systems named after other media: TOS (Tape Operating System), CAPS (CAssette Programming System), etc.

"operating systems capable of handling disks": I think it's important to keep that in mind, in particular since OP has not specified the type of computer. So the bigger picture is that a "Disk Operating System" probably insists on having working discs, as opposed to earlier OSes which used drums, various types of tape, or were limited to concatenating jobs loaded from cards and outputting to cards and printers.

@dave TOS also stands for Trammiel Operating System - the lowest level of the Atari ST OS (although Atari claimed it didn't).

@MarkMorganLloyd: Typically, a DOS would be in RAM rather than ROM (some Commodore drives being a notable exception to that general approach) and the most logical way to get one into RAM would be by loading it from a disk.  Most functions of a DOS wouldn't be particularly useful without a working disk, but that doesn't mean that a DOS would "insist" upoh having a working disk.

@supercat Bigger systems- i.e. things like the IBM S/360 running DOS/360- didn't have appreciable ROM.

@MarkMorganLloyd: If one has a CPU built out of discrete logic, adding some special-purpose logic to make its startup sequence fetch and execute data from an external storage device may be cheaper than building a ROM with code that would accomplish that task.  Such an approach might also have been somewhat workable with something like an 8080 if on startup all addresses near zero were mapped to the paper tape reader, and would stall the CPU until each byte became available, but I don't know if any systems were designed that way.

Atari DOS - for Atari ST it was GemDos.

@supercat Two examples from personal experience: a Burroughs B5000 series machine could read an 80-column card and treat it as binary, That was enough to read a couple more, after which it knew how to boot from tape. Alternatively, a B1700 series could start up by loading 16-bit opcodes from cassette (not cartridge etc.) tape. Needless to say these facilities were also used for test etc. purposes.

We see similar trends with SQL (MS-SQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.), CRMs (Zoho CRM, SugarCRM, Act! CRM, etc.) and even more recently with AI (OpenAI, Dante AI, Notion AI, Air AI, etc.) Sometimes it's just better to keep the acronym of what you are in your name.

@MarkMorganLloyd The S/360 architecture was distributed. If you wanted disk access, the mainframe CPU didn't handle that, it sent a channel command to a storage controller, which was essentially a separate computer running firmware (microcode). The system had so much firmware, IBM invented the floppy disk.

Yeah, QDOS was "Quick and Dirty Operating System" and it never became really clean.

You mean beside the point that they all are foremost about being an OS made to handle Disk storage? I guess that's the crux of engineers using a meaningful name, so people know what's about instead of inventing some trademarkable fantasy name envisioned by marketing(*1). The rest is how language works.
DOS is simply about what it is. Like Ketchup being a generic term for a certain type of condiment. To name a specific product it needs a prefix, like:

Heinz Ketchup - Ketchup from Heinz,
Bramwells Ketchup - Ketchup from Aldi or
Anni's Ketchup - Ketchup from General Mills.

They are all Ketchup and all taste somewhat similar, still not the same - like various DOS:

IBM PC-DOS from IBM
MS-DOS from Microsoft
DR-DOS from Digital Research

and so on. I guess the picture is obvious. It's about making clear that one is selling a DOS, not anything else. Selection between works via price and taste after being sure what one needs is Ketchup, not Mustard :)

Same question can be asked why all those Unix-like or Unix-Inspired OSes are branded somethingIX, right? It'll get the same answer, it's about marking them as the same thing - even if they taste totally different :))

*1 - Personally I'd say back then people were more focused on getting a product done and delivered in a meaningful way than wasting time to come up with fancy names needed for glossy advertisement. It was a simpler time, wasn't it?

But now of course ...

@dave Lovely :))

"Same question can be asked why..." ...or why various non-DOS operating systems contain OS in their name, like Mac OS (now macOS), BSD/OS, IBM's OS/360 and OS/2, etc. They're all OSes, even if they take different approaches to being OSes.

@ssokolow exactly.

macOS, iOS, ipadOS, tvOS, watchOS (but they have probably 90% identical source code). And IOS with three capital letters which is totally different and older so I think apple had to pay for permission to use iOS.

@dave That must be the successor of this company.

Just to provide an example of this (and feel free to edit this into your answer) it can be seen from the MS-DOS source code that this is how they thought at the time.  For example, This file from MS-DOS 2 makes numerous reference to "the DOS" in the same way as you would say "the OS", today, e.g. "it indicates whether or not the DOS was interrupted".

Wasn't IBM DOS just a re-brand of MS DOS though? Same ketchup, only different label?

@Lundin Well, beside the sequence being the other way around (MS-DOS being derivative of PC-DOS), MS-DOS was always machine independent and even the versions sold by MS for IBM compatible machines differed from PC-DOS ... i.e. providing a different taste.

In the early days of microcomputers, almost all forms of I/O not involving a disk were either sufficiently simple that they could be accomplished using code in a ROM, or sufficiently application-specific that they could best be accomplished by code within applications.  The purpose of a "disk operating system" was to provide a system for operating disks.  While other answers talk about the PC, this was even more true of other platforms such as the once-popular Apple II+ and derivatives.  A simpler printer port card for that platform would have I/O routines that fit in a 256-byte ROM; a more sophisticated expansion card might have I/O routines that stretched into an additional 2048-byte expansion area.  Apple DOS 3.3 needed to be loaded into RAM, where it occupied about 10K out of what would typically be 48K of RAM, even though it offered almost no abilities beyond the ability to load and store regions of memory to/from disk or perform I/O with text files.

Descriptive simplicity.  DOS = Disk Operating System.  It's an obvious thing to name an operating system that allows a user to interact with their computer's disk drives.
But I think the main reason is that, in the early 1980's, the name of the operating system wasn't considered important.  Because typical users didn't think of themselves as “using DOS”.  They used “an Apple II”, “a Commodore 64”, “an Atari”, “a Tandy”, or “an IBM PC”.  The computer itself got the attention, and the operating system was just an implementation detail for how you used floppy disks with the given computer.
With the rise of IBM clones, when you had a dozen or more manufacturers making mostly-mutually-compatible computers with the same OS, software publishers started saying “This program runs on MS-DOS” instead of “This program runs on the IBM PC.”

The similarity in naming has been addressed by others. You will find that a lot of OSes were not named DOS, like CP/M, VMS, OS/360, and so on. But you may find another group of names that share a similarity.
Like all OSes that were variants of MS-DOS were called DOS somehow, there is a big family of OSes that more or less are variants of UNIX and they often share the IX part. UNIX, AIX, XENIX and so on. Linux today follows the same line, and even though Apple says OS X is OS TEN, it is often pronounced OS X, referring to the UNIX heritage of the system.

another member in the family: Minix

DOS stands for Disk Operating system, probably because IBM called its mainframe operating system OS. When Microsoft wrote its operating system for the IBM PC the day of the Personal computer was born. Until then such computers were called 'micros'. They added MS-to the name DOS to differentiate it from IBM DOS.  DR-DOS from Digital Research followed the same naming convention. Note:  Both MS-DOS and IBM-DOS (both written by Microsoft) were based heavily on one of the first 'micro' operating systems called CP/M.

This looks like a quote from somewhere else - if so, that's fine, but please acknowledge it is a quote and credit the original author.

Thank you for the advice, but I didn't quote anyone in my answer. I have this information only because I've used all of the operating systems mentioned except CP/M.  Incidentally, after Microsoft dumped IBM to develop Windows, IBM came out with an operating system called OS-2, which I suspect was named after their mainframe system, OS. Thanks for taking the time  to comment.

This was prompted by you calling it “CP-M” instead of CP/M, and now you do the same with OS/2, which nobody who was there back then did.

Why would I lie?  All I wanted to do was try to answer a question, not start a debate.  I'm 75 years old and my memory about specifics is a little hazy.  I got interested in programming when a buddy loaned me his TRS-80 level 1 and taught myself basic.  I had a Commodor 64 and 128.  I learned COBOL and JCL at Boeing Computer Services back in '85 and played around with Borland C and Assembler, but I never approached programming as a career. I was a musician until I retired. Personally, I don't care if you believe me or not; I've got nothing to prove. 'Nuff said.
